# Receiving a TypeError ... is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently working on a website using express and handlebars. I am receiving an issue where the app throws back the error (below) although everything should be in place.

```
TypeError: compileAffiliates.start is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (F:\More Stuff\Coding\Affiliate Site V2\index.js:65:53)
at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

My index.js, shown below, requires the file `compileAffiliates` and then at ln65 it runs `compileAffiliates.start()`.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const passport = require("passport");
const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
const hbs = require("express-handlebars");
const config = require("./config.json");
const compileAffiliates = require("./compileAffiliates");
require("./passport-setup");

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/"));

app.set("view engine", "hbs");

app.engine("hbs", hbs( {
    extname: 'hbs',
    defaultView: 'default'
}));

app.use(cookieSession({
    name: "Affiliate",
    keys: ["key1","key2"]
}));

const isLogged = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.user && req.user.id === "") {
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect("/admin/failed");
    }
};

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    res.render("main", {config: config});
});
app.get("/admin/failed", (req, res) => res.send("Unauthorized"));
app.get("/admin/success", isLogged, (req, res) => res.send(`Admin Panel\n${req.user.id}`));

app.get("/admin/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['email', 'profile']}));

app.get("/admin/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/admin/failed' }),
    function(req, res) {
        // Successful authentication, redirect home.
        res.redirect("/admin/success");
    });

app.get("/admin/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.session = null;
    req.logout();
    res.redirect("/");
});

config.websiteAffiliates.output = compileAffiliates.start();

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("[APP] Listening to port 3000"));
```

My `compileAffiliates.js` looks like this:

```
let config = require("./config");

function start() {
    let output = ``;

    Object.keys(config.websiteAffiliates).forEach(key => {
        output += `
                <div class=col-md-3>
                    <div class="site-affiliate-container">
                        <img src="images/${config.websiteAffiliates[key].imgSrc}">
                        <div class="row row-style">
                            <div class="col col-style">
                                <span>${config.websiteAffiliates[key].refBonus}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col col-style">
                                <span>Code ${config.websiteAffiliates[key].refCode}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row row-style">
                            <button class="button button-type"><a href="${config.websiteAffiliates[key].imgLink}">Use Code</a></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
         `
    });

    return output;
}
```

and the config.json has this object:

```
"websiteAffiliates": {
    "1": {
      "refCode": "Code",
      "imgSrc": "1.png",
      "refBonus": "+5%",
      "imgLink": ""
    },
    "2": {
      "refCode": "Another Code",
      "imgSrc": "2.png",
      "refBonus": "+10%",
      "imgLink": ""
    }
  }
```

I'm completely lost as to why I am getting the error that the `compileAffiliates.start()` function does not exist. I'm lost as to how to fix it as to me, it looks like it should work but it doesn't. My file system should be like this:

```
Project
  -public
  -views
  compileAffiliates.js
  index.js
  config.json
```

Any help is really appreciated considering I'm stuck and I'm completely lost as to what's incorrect with my code. Thanks!

Comment: Your `compileAffiliates.js` doesn't export anything

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but what do you mean by export? Thanks!

Comment: in compileAffiliates.js add module.exports={start} at the end

Comment: Thank you, it worked.